# Which test when I have paired observations in more than two treatments?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric

I have doubts on which test I should use when I have measurements on the same individuals under more than 2 different conditions.
I have a sample of rats, on which was measured the effect of different light intensity on eye damage. Eye damage was measured on a scale from 0 (no damage) to 5 (severe damage).
So my data would looke something like this:

[image]

So the same individual has been scored multiple times, one for each light intensity (from 40lux to 400lux, with intervals of 20lux from one condition to the other).
Which test would be suitable for this type of data? I was wondering if a multi-way ANOVA would be suitable, but then I thought that eye damage scores are ordinal data so I should use a non-parametric alternative for this. However I do not know any non-parametric test for this.
What do you think I should do?
Please consider that I have very basic experience with statistics when giving your answer. The software I will be using is R Commander, which I am also just learning to use.
Thank you!

Comment: Was the order of light intensities randomized?  To your question, an ordinal proportional odds logistic model with repeated measures would be a good choice.  There are at least two ways to handle the repeats: add random intercepts fo subject, or use a first-order Markov process.  These are discussed [here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19).  You won't find menu-driven software that helps with this.

Comment: After looking more carefully on the Internet, I read about the Friedman test as a non-parametric alternative for the repeated measures ANOVA, and it looks like it might be good for my dataset. What do you think?

Comment: That test has very low power.